# How can type safety be guarded against implicit conversion in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose a method is as following:

```
void foo(int i)
{
}
```

Is there a way to make the following call illegal or generate an exception?

```
foo((short)3);
```

Comment: You can check class of parameter sent to method

Comment: @IwoKucharski, no, you can't. The method receives a primitive type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bruno's overloading will work, but if you are looking at preventing other types of casting, you can always box the integer into its Object class:

```
void foo(Integer i) {
    // handle data normally
}
```

This will prevent you from being able to send short arguments to it.

Comment: +1 nice! Just remember one drawback of this approach: you will have unnecessary boxing and unboxing, which might be a problem if this is called very frequently.

Comment: Wow, even though I gave an answer to this question, even I think this one is more ingenious.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this?

```
class AClass {
  void foo(int x) { /* do work */ }
  void foo(short x) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Actually, the original question in my mind is a more general one: how can a method be made type safe against any implicit conversion?  It would be great if one does not need to worry about how many possible implicit conversions there are.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about primitive types? Or are about reference types as well?

Comment: Primitive types. Thank you for pointing out the caveat of Farian's answer.  The methods of concern are not used frequently (e.g. not in a loop or similar situation).

Answer (score 3):

This solution may not be what you are looking for, but I would use **function overloading** to create one version of `void foo(int)`, which handles data like normal, and another version with the signature `void foo(short)` that handles data like it is an error. For example:

```
void foo(int i) {
    // handle data normally
}

void foo(short s) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("your message here");
}
```